# Why is the Jquery code fired more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that opens a modal from another page. One the modal is open if `.myBtn` is clicked the modal closes as expected and I get a click alert but when the `open modal` is pressed again I get 2 click alerts as the modal closes. Why is this and how can I keep all the elements in the dom 'working' but avoid the script being fired more than once? Many thanks.

Html

```
<button id="edit_credit" data-modal="myModal" class="btn btn-small btn-blue credit_btn">Open Modal</button>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    //Open Modal
    $('.credit_btn').on('click', function() {    
        $('.modal-container').load('modal_test.php',
           function() {
               $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
           }
       );

       $(document).on("click", ".myBtn", function(){
           alert('click');
       });
   });
});//End of doc
```

Modal_test.php (partial)

```
         <button type="submit" id="btn"  data-dismiss="modal" value="submit" class="btn btn-blue pull-right myBtn">
            Save</button>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-red pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </form>
    </div><!-- /.modal-footer -->
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Don't put an `onclick` within another `onclick`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of (see comments):

```
$('.credit_btn').on('click', function() {    
   // Everytime you click on .credit_btn
   // ...
   // You bind that event again (and again and again)
   $(document).on("click", ".myBtn", function(){
       alert('click');
   });
});
```

You can safely bind that once outside your click-event-handling

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    //Open Modal
    $('.credit_btn').on('click', function() {    
        $('.modal-container').load('modal_test.php',
           function() {
               $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
           }
       );
   });
   $(document).on("click", ".myBtn", function(){
       alert('click');
   });
});
```

(although I would rename that class from 'myBtn' to 'closeModal' or something like that, be specific when you code ;) )

Comment: That's brilliant, and thank you very much for the great explanation.